# Objective-C: Saving Archived Data to File Crashes

Tags: objective-c, file, serialization, nskeyedarchiver

my inquiry is this: I am saving and loading custom objects to file. Loading and creating files with the data works correctly, however, after a file has loaded, saving again crashes. Long story short, saving a file that has been loaded causes a crash upon saving.
The crash sends me to my custom objects m file:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
     [encoder encodeInteger:*(time) forKey:@"time"];
     [encoder encodeInteger:*(location) forKey:@"location"];
}
```

//====
Loading the data from file:

```
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
     NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
     globals.mainData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
```

//====
Saving to current file
My breakpoint stop me at: NSData *data = ... //and then crashes

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFileName];

    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:globals.mainData];   //crashes here
    BOOL saved = [data writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

    if (saved) {
        NSLog(@"Saved %@", currentFileName);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error - code 2 - Failure to save data");
    }
```

Any advice would be awesome and much appreciated!

Comment: What's the crash log? "`encodeInteger:*(time)`" That seems me wrong. But I don't know what's `time`.

Comment: I have a breakpoint on the NSData *data... line, afterward, it shoots me down to the object m file and stops on the first item with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and a memory location. All of the items are NSIntegers.

Comment: `[encoder encodeInteger:time forKey:@"time"];`? And the same for `location`?

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. I was used to working with strings in such a position and therefore was the root of this conundrum. Thank you.